# Copy formatted citation from helm-bibtex menu

Tags: org-mode, latex, bibtex, org-ref, helm-bibtex

I'm hoping to add a function "Copy formatted citation" to the `helm-bibtex` menu. i.e. When I open helm-bibtex, press tab on an entry and have the option there to copy a full formatted reference. Currently, there are options like "Copy entry to clipboard" and "Insert formatted citation(s)", but not copy a formatted citation to paste somewhere else.

I could do this myself but I'm time crunched and wonder if anyone has already written this function?

[image: screenshot of helm-bibtex tab]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add something like this to your init file to do that.

```
(helm-add-action-to-source
      "Copy formatted citation(s)"
      (lambda (_)
             (kill-new
              (mapconcat 'identity
                 (cl-loop for key in (helm-marked-candidates)
                      collect (org-ref-format-entry key))
                 "\n\n")))
      helm-source-bibtex)
```

Note this uses the org-ref formatter, but it looks like you are using org-ref already.